# Fast algorithm to determine best weights in a product-sum polynomial?

Tags: algorithm, math, mathematical-optimization, polynomials

I'm looking for a faster-than-brute-force algorithm for finding the best coefficients (aka weights) in a problem like this:

Define a *sample* as a series of *N* numbers.  In this case, say N=10.  The number of samples, *M*, is very large, say M=1000000.  This is essentially a matrix of M rows X N columns.  So the set of these samples looks like this:

```
S_0_0  S_0_1 S_0_2 ... S_0_N
S_1_0  S_1_1 S_1_2 ... S_1_N
...
S_M_0  S_M_1 S_M_2 ... S_M_N
```

Furthermore, there is a corresponding series of N weights.  The number of weight-series, *P*, is also huge, say P=2000000.  This is another matrix of P rows X N columns.  It looks similar to the sample set:

```
W_0_0  W_0_1 S_0_2 ... W_0_N
W_1_0  W_1_1 S_1_2 ... W_1_N
...
W_P_0  W_P_1 S_P_2 ... W_P_N
```

I'm trying to find the series of weights (i.e. the right row from the weight sets) that maximizes the following sum (i.e. what row *x*):

```
W_x_0 * S_0_0  +  W_x_1 * S_0_1  + ... +  W_x_N * S_0_N +
W_x_0 * S_1_0  +  W_x_1 * S_1_1  + ... +  W_x_N * S_1_N +
...
W_x_0 * S_M_0  +  W_x_1 * S_M_1  + ... +  W_x_N * S_M_N
```

Both sets of data (the *W*s and *S*s) are loaded from a file.  The *S*s are double-precision floating point numbers in the whole range supported by x86 CPUs (negative to positive).  The *W*s we can assume are integers.

The brute-force way of doing this is very straightforward: for each weight-row, multiply it by each sample-row in the sample set, while maintaining a running sum.  Keep track of the total sums for each weight-row, and pick the best at the end.

Now, where I think there is room for a smarter/faster algorithm is in the composition of the weight set.  We can assume only one number in the weight set changes per row.  So the weight set might look like this (here N=5 for brevity):

```
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 2
1 1 1 2 2
1 1 2 2 2
1 2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2 1
2 2 2 1 1
2 2 1 1 1
```

And so on.

In other words, in the brute-force approach, there will clearly be a lot of redundant computations.  If the datasets weren't so huge, one thought is to create a map/cache of every sample-weight product, and check that before computing.  But given the size of the dataset, I think the memory usage will be too high; also my intuition says the map/cache lookups might be slower than doing the naive multiplication.

Anyone aware of an algorithm or library that is appropriate here?

**Edit 1:** I had a typo in the original post: the weight set mistakenly showed two changes from one row to the next.  Indeed, there should only be one change per row.  Furthermore, don't read too much into the "pattern" of changes: the main idea is that there is only one change per row, but how those changes actually present can be modified to to suit a particular algorithm.

**Edit 2:** I *think* the example weight set is now truly only showing one change per row.

Comment: These two rows in your example show a change in two numbers: `2 1 1 1 1 -> 1 1 1 2 2`. Is that a mistake or did I misunderstand what you meant by "only one number in the weight set changes per row?" Did you mean "places" in the row or that the set (regardless of order) changes?

Comment: In the example weights you've given there's a change of more than 1 weight between rows 6 and 7 - is that a typo? Also, is there a pattern to which weights will change between rows, or is that random?

Comment: Building on the answer already given. Compute the column sums (`SUM_x = S_0_x + S_1_x + ... + S_M_x`). Then compute the answer (`A_x`) for the first weight series. The other answers can be computed incrementally. `A_1 = A_0 + SUM_4` `A_2 = A_1 - SUM_4 + SUM_3`

Comment: Yes, the original example weight set I showed was incorrect.  Now corrected (unless I made another typo!).  But the prose is right: there should be only one change per row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the very least, observe that

```
W_x_0 * S_0_0  +  W_x_1 * S_0_1  + ... +  W_x_N * S_0_N +
W_x_0 * S_1_0  +  W_x_1 * S_1_1  + ... +  W_x_N * S_1_N +
...
W_x_0 * S_M_0  +  W_x_1 * S_M_1  + ... +  W_x_N * S_M_N
```

equals

```
W_x_0 * (S_0_0 + S_1_0 +...S_M_0) +
W_x_1 * (S_0_1 + S_1_1 +...S_M_1) +
...
W_x_N * (S_0_N + S_1_N +...S_M_N)
```

which means we can sum the `S`'s, then run the operation for each weight vector in the list.

There may be an optimisation based on "farthest point query" (in multiple dimensions) which I'm not that educated about but will try to investigate.